# All of a sudden I get UnexpectedJavascriptException in my tests

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

Out of the box, I have this error showing in my laravel dusk tests.

> Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnexpectedJavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
>     (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64).

Would  anyone know why this is appearing?

Thanks
Danny

Comment: Please post your test.